# Netezza convert char to numeric - arithmetic - and convert again to char

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a field PersonNumb which is varchar(30) and needs to get converted to numeric, than do some arithmetic(in this case some simple addition Value + 10, just for example) and than convert this field again to varchar.

I do cut off the '|' to convert the field to number, without blanks or other characters, everything fine.

```
 to_number(translate(PersonNumb,'|',''),999999999999999999999999999999) AS NewPersonNumb;
```

Than i do the arithmetic with
`update XX..YY set NewPersonNumb = NewPersonNumb + 10`;

But the last step wont work, the field is **still numeric** and **not varchar**.

`update XX..YY set NewPersonNumb = to_char(NewPersonNumb,'999999999999999999999999999999');`

Put the whole statement in one row doesnt work too...

`update XX..YY set NewPersonNumb = to_char(NewPersonNumb + 10,'99999999999999999999999999');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following its working for me .

```
TEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table YY (PersonNumb varchar(30)) distribute on random;
CREATE TABLE
TEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into YY values('22222222|111111|4');
INSERT 0 1
TEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> update yy set PersonNumb = to_number(translate(PersonNumb,'|',''),999999999999999999999999999999)+10 ;
UPDATE 1
TEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from YY;
   PERSONNUMB
-----------------
 222222221111124
```

Comment: I was just wroting an answer, telling that the PersonNumb gonna be numeric after your line, but i tried it and you are right... your line works too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone will need it

Put everything in the select

`(to_number(translate(PersonNumb,'|',''),99999999999999999999999999999) + 10)::varchar(30) AS NewPersonNumb`